# Influence of independent variables on boolean functions?

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, graph-theory, boolean-algebras

Suppose a simple connected graph $G$ where its vertices are assumed to be independent. An event with uncertainty corresponds to each vertex. My instructor guides me that even though the vertices (variables) are assumed to be independent, the events can influence the boolean functions such as existence of a path and mentioned [Kahn-Kalai-et al's work The Influence of Variables on Boolean Functions](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~kalai/kkl.ps). I would like to understand this deeper. Can you recommend similar works or related works related to graph theory? Or works specifically on independent variables and their influence on boolean functions?

Please help me understand the distinction made with the vertices, variables and events in order to understand their different influences on boolean functions with independent variables. I am confused by the jargon.

Thank you.

Comment: Ryan O'Donnell has written a monograph on the topic, Analysis of Boolean functions.